# Get <td> value with Knockout JS and put into a div

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I have an html table with the last column hidden. When I click a table row, I want to take this hidden column value and put it into a div. Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tzD4T/390/

the ko model:

```
    function ViewModelTrazas(data) {
      var self = this;
      self.trazas = ko.observableArray();
      array = self.trazas;
    }

    function push(){
       array.push({
            Fecha: ko.observable('a'),
            Maquina: ko.observable('b'),
            TipoEvento: ko.observable('c'),
            Mensaje: ko.observable('d')
       });
     }

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModelTrazas(), document.getElementById('divDataGrid'));
    push();
```

The table:

```
<table id="datagrid" style="width: 100%;">
         <thead style="text-align:left">
             <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Machine</th>
                <th>Event type</th>
                <th>Detail</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
         <tbody data-bind="foreach: trazas">
             <tr>
                  <td data-bind=" text: Fecha"></td>
                  <td data-bind=" text: Maquina"></td>
                  <td data-bind=" text: TipoEvento"></td>
                  <td data-bind=" text: Mensaje"></td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
```

I've tried to do it with jquery but this sample code didn't worked:

```
$('datagrid tr').click(function(){
 var detail = $(this).val();
 // put the value into div
  ... 
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to render it in the table in the beginning? Why don't you just show the details when the user clicks on the row? Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/Bt8fg/

Comment: @nemesv yes, it's that what i want but it says me `unable to parse bindings, $parent is not defined` but the fiddle seems to be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzD4T/389/). It's pretty simple.
I just just added a selectedRow obsevable and selectRow event handler.

The view :

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="divDataGrid" style="margin-top:-4px;
                                    height: 200px; overflow:auto;">
                <table id="datagrid" style="width: 100%;">
                    <thead style="text-align:left">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Machine</th>
                            <th>Event type</th>
                            <th>Detail</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: trazas">
                        <tr data-bind="click: $parent.selectRow">
                            <td data-bind=" text: Fecha"></td>
                            <td data-bind=" text: Maquina"></td>
                            <td data-bind=" text: TipoEvento"></td>
                            <td data-bind=" text: Mensaje"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<span>Detail:</span>
<br/>
<div data-bind="with: seletedRow">
    <div data-bind="text: Mensaje"></div>
</div>
```

Js :

```
var array;

function ViewModelTrazas(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.trazas = ko.observableArray();
    array = self.trazas;
    self.selectRow = function (row) {
        self.seletedRow(row);
    }
    self.seletedRow = ko.observable();
}

[...]
```

**[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzD4T/389/)**

Comment: Can you try to do the same with this updated fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/tzD4T/390/ I've just updated the `ko.applyBindings(new ViewModelTrazas(), document.getElementById('divDataGrid'));` and it does not work.

Comment: I wrapped your view with a div (id = gridAndDetail).
http://jsfiddle.net/tzD4T/391/